# How to add image on google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, web-applications, asp.net-web-api

I am newbie.I want to make web app based on google-map.I have successfully written a code for displaying google map.Here is my html code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 16px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

    </style>
    <title>Places search box</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>

function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  var input = (
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    (input));

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search your location here">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now i want to put image icon on streets.Please give your useful suggestion, how it can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly on streets"?  You only want the stars on streets, but don't really care where their position is? What is a "star"? Do you have a particular icon in mind?  How many "random" stars do you want?

Comment: Sorry for inconvience in my question.I want to put 100 similar image icon on different position of street.

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario, you can add image markers to the map.

**To draw a marker with image:**

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        map: map,
        icon: '/path/to/image.png',
        zIndex: 1
});
```

All you need is specifying the coordinate of each image to be drawn onto the map where you can randomly generate them. Keep in mind that you have to create a marker object for each of the stars you want to draw. Do not reuse the marker object.

Comment: Definitely. You will need to `new google.maps.Marker` for each of the icons you want to draw. For each of them, you will need to specify `(lat,lng)` of the coordinate you want to draw. You may first try draw at a specific `lat,lng` and try adding displacement to it to see the distribution of the positions.

Comment: I want to display similar image icon "image.png" at different coordinate of map.is it neccessary to declare coordinate of each image where i want to draw it on map?